# Can I pass value via next call to a delegated generator?

Tags: javascript, generator

```js
function* foo(x) {
    if (x < 3) {
        x = yield* foo( x + 1 );
    }
    yield x * 2;
}

const it = foo( 1 );

console.log(it.next());
console.log(it.next());
console.log(it.next());
```

This code shows these values in the console

```
{value: 6, done: false}
(index):42 {value: NaN, done: false}
(index):43 {value: NaN, done: false}
```

It looks that value returned from `yield* foo(x + 1)` is always `undefined` even if I pass some values to the `next` like this

```
console.log(it.next(1));
console.log(it.next(2));
console.log(it.next(3));
```

Why the `1`, `2`, and `3` values are ignored?

Comment: Because `foo` does not return any value, so `x = yield* foo( x + 1 );` yields `undefined`.

Comment: From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield*): *"The value of yield\* expression itself is the value returned by that iterator when it's closed (i.e., when done is true)."*

Comment: What did you try to do? `next()` does not take [any parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Generator#G%C3%A9n%C3%A9rateurs_historiques), and returns the value of the generator itself it's done.

Comment: @soywod: `.next` does accept an argument: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator/next . That value will be the return value of the `yield` expression. But `yield*` is different.

Comment: You can change your code to `return yield x * 2;` but whether it has the effect you want I don't know. You didn't really explain what you are trying to achieve here.